# The colors in Resident Evil 7 are *completely* off

Tags: technical-issues, pc, resident-evil-7

It almost looks like that I'm running the game without textures (you can enlarge the images):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm running the game at the highest settings (with some exceptions such as the unwanted chromatic aberration). This issue manifested after starting the game again  with [the gold edition](https://store.steampowered.com/bundle/5837/RESIDENT_EVIL_7_biohazard_Gold_Edition/) — I played past the midway point at release and no graphical issues were present.

I have tried fully reinstalling the game and verified the integrity of files on Steam. I have Intel i7-4770K (@3.50GHz) and Nvidia RTX 2070 Super (drivers are up to date), well exceeding the recommend system specifications. HDR is disabled and appears to be grayed out on non-supported monitors.

The game looks better in a shade, but no visual aspect seems to be entirely right:

[image]

[image]

And for reference, the real-time main menu seems to be rendered flawlessly:

[image]

Comment: [Real is Brown](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RealIsBrown)?

Comment: I admit that I haven't played RE7 recently, but from memory the beginning of the game has a *lot* of brown in it.

Comment: **WARNING:** TV TROPES LINK IN COMMENTS.  Click only if you want to lose the next two hours of your life.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yet you came back from the land of the undead to warn us of its perils. There is hope for us yet!

Comment: @Powerlord: That's correct, but you can see in [any walkthrough video](https://youtu.be/B9h4yYnstkA?t=215) that the leaves have natural color and no texture looks like in my game. This isn't any filter or color palette, but flat-out broken.

Comment: Have you tried running the game in borderless window? Also, looking at the picture featured [here](https://wccftech.com/resident-evil-7/), it almost seems like it's supposed to look like that, except for different AA settings - maybe there's a problem there?

Comment: @Joachim: Yes, I've tried both borderless and exclusive fullscreen. If you're referring to the "headline picture", it's captured indoors and caused by lightning.

Comment: So interiors have the same washed-out look in your game?

Comment: @Joachim: I haven't checked how the interiors look yet, I haven't had the desire to play past the intro.

Comment: Based on what I encountered searching for RE7 graphical problems, it seems there is a huge difference in the lighting (or color palette) between interiors and exteriors, and that could also explain the fact that your main menu looks fine.

Comment: I've discovered that some graphical setting causes the bug: [the game looks vastly better at the lowest settings (compare to the second image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9tEc.jpg). I'll answer the question when I discover the culprit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was caused by "subsurface scattering", which according to the game's description "improves skin rendering"... this can be a bug in Nvidia's drivers (436.48 version currently installed) or in the game.

comparison:

[image: subsurface scattering off]

[image: subsurface scattering on]

enabling reflections also changes the look of the scene significantly:

[image: reflections on]

Comment: Glad to see you got fixed. It's strange that subsurface scattering has such a dramatic effect on the overall look of the game, though.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a common bug.

- [Apparently](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0Ne62jh2Qg), you can fix the issue by changing `HDRMode=1` to `HDRMode=0` in the *re7_config.ini* file, under the header `[Display]`.
  The file can be found in the Resident Evil 7 game folder (under '*/Steam/steamapps/*').

Comment: The setting was set to `HDRMode=1` despite that HDR is shown as disabled in the game.

Comment: Unfortunately the game looks the same after setting `HDRMode=0` — a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: The linked Reddit thread is for RE2.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up; removed. Sorry to hear it didn't work out.

Comment: It's also possible that `HDRMode=1` means OFF and `HDRMode=2` ON (see [this comment](https://steamcommunity.com/app/418370/discussions/0/133256959369549156/#c133256959370955603)). Sometimes this syntax is used in configuration files instead, albeit I don't know f `0` is omitted entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an RTX2070 and had to use the following settings else the image was wash washed out with bronzed watercolour effect or way too dark.

Mode: Window Borderless (Full Screen / HDR Mode completelry darkens the image)

I ran Geforce Experience and it came up with the following for optimal setting which gave the correct colours:
Anti-Aliasing: TAA (gives a good FPS)
Ambient Occlusion: HBAO+
Color Space: SRGB

The remainder I set for what I wanted as my preferred FPS vs Quality.

I tend not to update graphic drivers unless I have to. That's more usefull for recent releases. It creates more problems than it solves with older games.

To rollback to a previous Nvidia driver use this link:
https://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/find.aspx?lang=en-uk